# Similar phrase to 'rhetorical device' for 'strategy of convincing others'?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to find a phrase that means "the way he convinces people".  It's similar to "rhetorical device".

Someone has a strategy for convincing people (for example, speaking in a friendly tone, trying to scare them, appealing to their sense of reason or humor, etc.).  What is this called, formally?  Can you think of a few words?

Comment: If positive, *persuasion*, else, *manipulation*.

Comment: Or perhaps, **passive-aggressive behaviour**. Or even **guilt tripping**

Comment: I remember seeing _persuasion_ used in the sense of _manipulation_ too.

Comment: @alwayslearning *persuasion* is an umbrella term for all kinds of influence.

Comment: It could be persuasion style.  http://poweressence.com/persuasive-techniques/

Comment: Useful link: http://poweressence.com/persuasive-techniques/

Comment: Another useful link: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/50-rhetorical-devices-for-rational-writing/ . Enjoy.  Anaculothon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the phrase you're looking for is Rhetorical Modes.
One of the most common Rhetorical modes is called Argumentation. You also have: Cause-Effect, Exemplification, Narration, Compare and Contrast, and many others. Rhetorical modes are used in writing and speaking.

Comment: This is the answer that got me there.  I looked for persuasive techniques and persuasive devices, and I got a lot of good results.  I don't know why I couldn't find the phrase from the root, but I think the examples in this answer refreshed my memory.

Answer (score 0):

How about **powers of persuasion**?

From Merriam-Webster:

> [**persuasion**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persuasion): the
>   act of causing people to do or believe something : the act or activity
>   of persuading people

This seems analogous to your example of *rhetorical device*.

Comment: Richard: I can give you some back story.  I was reading a journal article about secondary teaching building up to a presentation section in my lesson about persuasive devices.  Apparently, teens with poor persuasive devices have a lot more trouble adapting, socially.  And teens who don't socially adapt are at a much higher risk for a variety of different troubles (for example, under-employment, experimenting with drugs, and so-on).  So, I thought I could bait the kids into getting interested in the discussion.  And it was very successful in some of the classes.  But I can't remember the term.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Rhanks for the back story. Jujitsu?

Answer (score 0):

There's a *word* which comes close - ***persuasion***.

Definitions from Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[persuasion](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/persuasion)** *noun* (CHANGING IDEAS)
>
> ​the action of persuading someone or of being persuaded:
>
> It took a lot of persuasion to convince the committee of the
> advantages of the new plan.
>
> She will help you - she just needs a little gentle persuasion.
>
> The occasion will be a test of the senator's powers of persuasion (=
> his ability to persuade people).
>
> **[persuade](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/persuade)**
> *verb* ​ to make someone do or believe something by giving them a good reason to do it or by talking to that person and making them believe
> it:
>
> If she doesn't want to go, nothing you can say will persuade her.
>
> [ +
> (that) ] It's no use trying to persuade him (that) you're innocent.
>
> [ + to infinitive ] He is trying to persuade local and foreign
> businesses to invest in the project.

Note: It appears that this answer clashes with the one submitted by Richard Kayser apparently seconds before this one. I am letting it be, with this disclaimer.

Comment: I beat you by 12 seconds. :-) We seem to be tracking one another tonight.

Comment: @RichardKayser, yes. I have added a clarifying note accordingly. :)

Comment: That's totally unnecessary. If I could edit your answer, I would. I propose we do the following: you delete your note; we each delete our parts of this exchange. When I see your content disappear, I'll delete mine. I just wanted to say hi.

Comment: If you want to leave the note, I'm fine with that, too.

Comment: I have edited it further to clarify further that your's was submitted first, FWIW. I think we are just being transparent here.

Comment: Transparency is a goodness. :-)

Comment: Just FYI. Always mention your sources by name, along with links to it.

Comment: Sure, I do it always; missed it now, and corrected it. I remember seeing the citations missing from other answers, including those of more _reputed_ users, though.

Comment: Perhaps it is something like persuasion.  For example, "method of persuasion".  For example, in D&D, there's "diplomacy" and "intimidation" (the sooner being good and the latter being evil).  So, the method of persuasion....  I think it's persuasive techniques or persuasion strategies (or something very close to that).

Comment: Perhaps it is something like persuasion.  For example, "method of persuasion".  For example, in D&D, there's "diplomacy" and "intimidation" (the sooner being good and the latter being evil).  So, the method of persuasion....  I think it's persuasive techniques or persuasion strategies (or something very close to that).

Answer (score 0):

I have a child in middle school.  In his English classes they call it

**persuasive argument**.